# return type of order() in R

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R and I'm trying to debug a special case in my code. 
In the following lines what I'm doing is getting a vector `x` sorted, based a column that surely exists. Naturally, I would expect `sorted.data` to be the same and in most cases it is.

```
print (paste("x=",typeof(x)))
print (x)
sorted.data <- x[order(x[[max.column]]), ]
print (paste("type of sorted=", typeof(sorted.data)))
print (sorted.data)
```

In most cases the output of the above code is:

```
[1] "x= list"
    V1  V5
8   10   0
16   7   0
18   7   0
20   1  96
24   9   0

[1] "type of sorted= list"
    V1  V5
8   10   0
16   7   0
18   7   0
24   9   0
31   5   0
```

But at some point, the output is:

```
[1] "x= list"    # Expected. a vector with 1 column
    V1
8   10
16   7
18   7
24   9
26  10

[1] "type of sorted= integer"  # This shouldn't happen
 [1]  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  4
```

What could be going wrong? Why the return value changes?

Comment: `x[order(x[[max.column]]), ]` should not work if it is truly a `list`, are you certain it is not a `data.frame`? (That's how it's being displayed here, anyway.) Assuming it's a `data.frame`, then a default mode when indexing the rows, *"the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension"* which, when a single column, means it is coerced to a vector. Try using `x[order(x[[max.column]]),,drop=TRUE]`. (See [`help("[")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).)

Comment: @r2evans Actually, it's `drop = FALSE`, as it should be. (Just tested it.) `sorted.data <- x[order(x[[ncol(x)]]), , drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: Of course ... tested both sides to make sure, copy/pasted the wrong one, thanks for the check.

Comment: @r2evans If you could put your comment as an answer because it worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your data looks very much like a `data.frame`, which is very much like a `list`. If it were truly not a `data.frame`, then your comma-indexing (`x[order(x[[max.column]]), ]`) should not work, so I'm assuming it's a `data.frame`.

One thing I find occasionally frustrating with `data.frame` indexing (and `array`s, too), the default behavior is that *"the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension"* (extracted from [`help("[")`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html)). This means that when the indexing results in only one column (or row), it is returned as a vector. To preempt this, add `,drop=FALSE` to your indexing:

```
x[order(x[[max.column]]),,drop=FALSE]
```

(Thanks to Rui Barradas for correcting my errant comment above.)